# Is this sentence correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I've been told by a person that the sentence below is incorrect grammatically and it does not make any sense. Specifically, that person told me that the part ''could do'' is wrong. ''Could do'', for him, should rather be replaced by ''had'' to make sense.

*Pretending to be a beggar on the street was the only way such a shameless individual as you could do.*

As I'm not a native speaker, I'm not sure whether this sentence is correct or not grammatically? Therefore, I'd like to ask some native speaker here about whether the part ''could do'' is correct and whether the whole sentence is correct ? thanks

Comment: This sentences doesn't make any sense.  Could do what?  And replacing "could do" with "had" makes **significantly** less sense.

Comment: Could do what ? Could PRETEND. ''Do'' in ''Could do'' here corresponds to ''to pretend'', a verb form of pretending. What's wrong with could do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replace *way* by *thing*, then your sentence is grammatical and makes sense:

> Pretending to be a beggar on the street was the only *thing* such a
>   shameless individual as you could do.

This works because you can do *things* but you cannot do *ways*. For example,

> - Begging was the only *thing* (that) she could do.
> - ?Begging was the only *way* (that) she could do.

However, you can *have* ways. So your friend's suggestion:

> Pretending to be a beggar on the street was the only *way* such a
>   shameless individual as you *had*

is grammatical and makes sense

Comment: Or, in the original sentence, replace *do* with *act*.

Comment: Hmmm. Possibly. However, I think what the author is aiming for might be something like "***Pretending to be a beggar on the street was a thing (that) only such a shameless individual as you could do.***" I think maybe the *was/thing* confusion is coming about because the OP is thinking about *behaviour* or *ways of behaving*, perhaps. Of course, in English, you can't *do* a behaviour ... (or *do* a way either) :)

Comment: @Araucaria. Is your _Hmmm. Possibly._ directed at my answer or Clare's comment? Anyway, the original sentence is somewhat strangely expressed (the _thing/way_ issue notwithstanding). Your repositioning of _only_ makes a much more natural sentence - if this is the OP's intended meaning.

Comment: @Shoe It was for you :)

Comment: @Araucaria.  Hmmm! Which part of my answer is the _possibly_ directed at? :)

Comment: @Shoe I hadn't chosen my word very carefully there. What I meant was just *that's a possible interpretation of the OP's original communicative intention*. I wasn't saying that anything in your post was 'possibly (in)correct'!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native speaker and I think that these options would work for you:

*Pretending to be a beggar on the street is the only option for a shameless individual, such as yourself.*

or

*The best that a shameless individual, such as yourself, could do is pretend to be a beggar on the street.*

The problem initially is the use of "way." You need a **preposition** after "way" in order to make a sentence that makes sense. For example:

*"Pretending to be a beggar on the street was the only way, **for** such a shameless individual as you."*

In this sentence "way" means: the method, style, or manner of doing something.

Additionally, "could do" doesn't work with the sentence.

*"You could do **better** next time,"* or *"was it the **best** that you could do?"* are correct ways of using "could do."

You also need an **adjective** that describes "could do." For example, "It was the best that I could do."

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm not a teacher so I don't have the best answer but here is a website that might be able to help you:

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/can-or-could